# django RecursionError : maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I have implemented membership by building a custom user model in the django rest framework. By the way, the following error occurs when you code and run the server.

> RecursionError : maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a
> Python object

Here is full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\api\views.py", line 16, in post
    serializer.save()   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line  212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\api\serializers.py", line 61, in create
    return User.objects.create_user(**validate_data)   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\api\models.py", line 29, in create_user
    user = self.create_user(   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\api\models.py", line 29, in create_user
    user = self.create_user(   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\api\models.py", line 29, in create_user
    user = self.create_user(   [Previous line repeated 951 more times]   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\api\models.py", line 31, in create_user
    email=self.normalize_email(email),   File "D:\school\대회 및 프로젝트\CoCo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 25, in normalize_email
    email_name, domain_part = email.strip().rsplit('@', 1) RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object [20/Aug/2020 09:55:57] "POST /auth/signUp HTTP/1.1" 500 3947748
```

Can I know how to solve this error? Here is my code.

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class UserManager (BaseUserManager) :
    def create_user (self, username, email, profile, password=None) :

        if username is None :
            raise TypeError('Users should have a username')

        if email is None :
            raise TypeError('Users should have a email')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            profile=profile,
        )
        
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_user (self, username, email, profile, password=None) :

        if password is None :
            raise TypeError('Password should not be none')

        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            profile=profile,
            password=password
        )
            
        user.create_user(username, email, profile, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        return user

class User (AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin) :
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    profile = models.ImageField(default='media\default_image.jpeg')
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'profile']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__ (self) :
        return self.email
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import User
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer, TokenRefreshSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from allauth.account import app_settings as allauth_settings
from allauth.utils import email_address_exists
from allauth.account.adapter import get_adapter
from allauth.account.utils import setup_user_email
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Base64ImageField (serializers.ImageField) :

    def to_internal_value (self, data) :
        from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
        import base64
        import six
        import uuid

        if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
            if 'data:' in data and ';base64,' in data:
                header, data = data.split(';base64,')

            try:
                decoded_file = base64.b64decode(data)
            except TypeError:
                self.fail('invalid_image')

            file_name = str(uuid.uuid4())[:12]
            file_extension = self.get_file_extension(file_name, decoded_file)
            complete_file_name = "%s.%s" % (file_name, file_extension, )
            data = ContentFile(decoded_file, name=complete_file_name)

        return super(Base64ImageField, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def get_file_extension (self, file_name, decoded_file) :
        import imghdr

        extension = imghdr.what(file_name, decoded_file)
        extension = "jpg" if extension == "jpeg" else extension

        return extension

class customRegisterSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer) :
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)
    profile = Base64ImageField(use_url=True)
    
    class Meta :
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'username', 'profile', 'password']

    def validate (self, attrs) :
        email = attrs.get('email', '')
        username = attrs.get('username', '')
        profile = attrs.get('profile', '')

        return attrs
        
    def create (self, validate_data) :
        return User.objects.create_user(**validate_data)
```

Comment: You are calling `user.create_user(....)`  and `self.create_user(...)` inside the `create_user(...)` method, which causing the error.

Comment: wow .. so thanks !